# Getting data from HBase using SparkStreaming with Kafka

Tags: hbase, spark-streaming

I am trying to integrate SparkStreaming with HBase.  I am calling following APIs to connect to HBase:

```
HConnection hbaseConnection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(conf);
hBaseTable = hbaseConnection.getTable(hbaseTable);
```

Since I cannot get the connection and broadcast the connection each API call to get data from HBase is very expensive.  I tried using `JavaHBaseContext (JavaHBaseContext hbaseContext = new JavaHBaseContext(jsc, conf))` by using hbase-spark library in CDH 5.5 but I cannot import the library from maven.  Has anyone been able to successfully resolve this issue.

I am trying to use the latest APIs to connect HBase and SparkStreaming on Cloudera.

Some of the JIRA items mentioned here.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/apache-spark-comes-to-apache-hbase-with-hbase-spark-module/

I am using `JavaHBaseContext hbaseContext = new JavaHBaseContext(jssc.sparkContext(), conf);`
Then called bulk Get API
`hbaseContext.streamBulkGet(TableName.valueOf(tableName), 2, lines, new GetFunction2(), new ResultFunction());`

But this bulk API is invoked during initialization not during each streaming message. Also used:

```
hbaseContext.foreachPartition(jDStream,new VoidFunction<Tuple2<Iterator<String>, Connection>>() {
      public void call(Tuple2<Iterator<String>, Connection> t)throws Exception { ...}
```

The API exists but somehow it  is not working for streaming message.  Also tried `hbaseContext.streamMap(jdstream, new Function<Tuple2<Iterator<String>, Connection>, Iterator<String>>()` but it is not working either.

Do we have an example of how to get data using the spark streaming API.

Comment: I cannot pull the maven repository mentioned here.  http://hbase.apache.org/hbase-spark/dependency-info.html

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set up the connection? If your connection code is only on the driver, make sure the connection object is serializable

I am using Cassandra, what I did is that I have a scala object where I have cassandra connection object. In this way, on both driver and workers, at least there is one exeuctor-scoped connection object

Comment: Thanks for your response Grant. I was calling HBAse API directly to get data from HBase but that approach is expensive because objects are not serialized.  So tried using the newer version of spark hbase API mention here http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/apache-spark-comes-to-apache-hbase-with-hbase-spark-module/, the API works fine with normal Rdd but not with streaming.

Comment: Cassandra spark connector has APIs which store RDD or DStream directly to Cassandra, however sometimes these APIs are not flexible. So I never use them, instead I used other APIs which set up the connection, get the session and execute statements, etc. So the trick is that you have to initialize the connection on each spark executor. Although the connector could be serializable, better to create them per spark executor